# c# TypeInitializationException when initializing generic collection within static constuctor

Tags: c#, constructor, static

I'm getting a System.TypeInitializationException exception on line 9 when running this code in which I attempt to fill a generic list in the class'static constuctor.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication5_static_constructor {
    public static class DataRepository {
        public static List<DefinedField> Tables;
        static DataRepository() {
            Console.WriteLine("static DataRepository constructor fired");
            Tables.Add(new DefinedField("ID"));  **//this is line 9**
        }
    }

    public class DefinedField {
        string _tableName;
        public DefinedField(string tableName) {
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

        public string TableName {
            get { return _tableName; }
            set { _tableName = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Call code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication5_static_constructor {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<DefinedField> x = DataRepository.Tables;
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly is causing the error and how do i solve it, please?

Edit: Also there is an inner exception of the type NullReferenceException
Is a static constructor not capable of initializing new objects?

Comment: Generally when you get exceptions you dont understand have a look at the InnerException. This would have been a NullReferenceException which would tell you the cause.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind for the next time. I'm glad you guys helped me so quickly. Actually it would've taken me a while to figure this out, probably because I'm more used to write python scripts

Comment: @CathalMF Generally yes, but not when the exception happens in a static constructor.

Comment: @Maarten I recreated this myself and it has a NullRefererenceException in the InnerException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your static property `Tables` is not initialized. It is showing as an TypeInitializationException because the exception is firing in the static constructor. So the exception happens when the type `DataRepository` is being initialized.

The solution is to set it to an empty list.

```
public static List<DefinedField> Tables = new List<DefinedField>();
```

Comment: oops thank you!!! - got to wait a few minutes to accept this answer :)